# PostgreSQL transaction that has anormally no effect

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL program to simulate transactions between accounts in a bank.
In order to test my system, I tried with a PostgreSQL transaction that simulates a banking transaction. However, this transaction seems to have no effect while, normally, I would like the `failed_transactions` table to get a record :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clients, accounts, transactions, failed_transactions, successful_transactions CASCADE;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client int,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(id),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    amount float
);

CREATE TABLE failed_transactions
(
    id serial,
    account_id integer,
    attempted_amount float,
    timestamp timestamp DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE TABLE successful_transactions
(
    id serial,
    account_id integer,
    attempted_amount float,
    timestamp timestamp DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_failed_transaction()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.balance<-500 THEN
            INSERT INTO failed_transactions(account_id, attempted_amount)
                        VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.balance-OLD.balance);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_successful_transaction()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.balance>=-500 THEN
            INSERT INTO successful_transactions(account_id, attempted_amount)
                        VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.balance-OLD.balance);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_for_failed_transactions BEFORE UPDATE ON accounts
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE FUNCTION log_failed_transaction();

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_for_successful_transactions AFTER UPDATE ON accounts
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE FUNCTION log_successful_transaction();


INSERT INTO clients VALUES (10, 'Client 1');
INSERT INTO clients VALUES (14, 'Client 2');
INSERT INTO clients VALUES (25, 'Client 3');

INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (8, 2000, 14);
INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (12, 650, 10);
INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (2, 300, 25);



BEGIN;
DO $$
DECLARE
    payer integer := 10; --payer referenced by bank1
    recipient integer := 25; --recipient referenced by bank2
    amount float := 100; --amount to transfer
BEGIN
    -- Attempt to execute a query that might fail
    UPDATE accounts
        SET balance = balance - amount
        WHERE client = payer;
    UPDATE accounts
        SET balance = balance + amount
        WHERE client = recipient;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'An error occurred: %', SQLERRM;
END $$;
COMMIT;



SELECT * FROM successful_transactions;
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger checks BEFORE UPDATE if the NEW.balance >=-500. But the new balance is unknown since you didn't update the record yet (BEFORE, remember) and you didn't do any calculation using the amount that has to be transferred from A to B.

This logic can also be implemented without a trigger, see the update query, just by using a WHERE condition. And when implementing this, you have to check both update statements, because when one of them fails, the other one must also fail. Your current logic just executes both updates, no matter what the balance is.

Besides that, FLOAT is not a great data type for financial information, it's not an exact number.

---

And something else, you're using a statement trigger. In a statement trigger you can't use row level information from a single record:

> NEW record  new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level
> triggers. This variable is **null** in statement-level triggers and for
> DELETE operations.

Change your trigger to FOR EACH **ROW** to solve this issue.

Your check constraint will also conflict with the trigger. I would recommend to review and optimize your proces and code. The table transactions is also obsolete and has no relation with any other table. And it's not used anyway.

Comment: I put "AFTER" rather than "BEFORE" but the result was apparently the same.

Comment: @Lapin Change the trigger to a row level trigger. Besides that, I would change the entire setup

Comment: What do you mean by "row level trigger" ?

Comment: @Lapin You currently have a statement trigger, a trigger that fires just once of every statement, every query. However you do need a row level trigger, a trigger that fires on every row that is involved. And again, the CHECK constraint will prevent a successful query anyway, the query will be aborted before the trigger fires.